# Unable to view inner tab from main tab in using titanium in android device?

Tags: android, titanium

I making application for Android and ipone using titanium sdk  in which i have used tabgroup.but when i go from one one screen to another screen in same tab.tab is dissable in second screen while it is visible i iphone device not in Android device.
I have used fiollwing codeto go from main window to inner window in same tab.

**

```
Continue.addEventListener('click',function(e)
      {
        var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
            url:'tab1_continue.js',backgroundColor:'#fff'
        });
        Titanium.UI.currentTab.open(win,{animated:true});**
```

it does not work on android.plz help

Answer (score 0):

The "url" property is causing the window to be heavyweight, which means it cannot be a child of the tab group (it necessarily takes up everything). Read more on the discussion in the Appcelerator Q&A [about this topic](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/132573/tabgroup-child-window-covers-tabgroup).

Answer (score 0):

if this is in "app.js" then use this code

```
Continue.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
            url:'tab1_continue.js',backgroundColor:'#fff'
        });
        <tabName>.open(win,{animated:true});**
});
```

otherwise

```
Continue.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
            url:'tab1_continue.js',backgroundColor:'#fff'
        });
        Titanium.UI.currentTab.open(win,{animated:true});
});
```